# Specifying TODO formatting in a theme file

Tags: org-mode, themes

I have just created my first custom theme for Emacs using `autothemer`. In my theme file, I specify all the faces I'd like to use, including those used by [org-mode](/questions/tagged/org-mode).

I notice now that my theming is split across my `init.el` file and my theme file. For example, while I define my org-mode headers (e.g., `org-level-*`) in my theme file, I define my TODO keywords along with their faces in my `init.el`.

This code is what usually appears in my `init.el`.

```
(setq org-todo-keywords
      '((sequence "TASK(t)" "UNDERWAY(u)" "WAITING(w@/@)" "|" "DONE(d)" "CANCELLED(c@)"))) 

(setq org-todo-keyword-faces
      '(("TASK" . "#9f21e3") ("UNDERWAY" . "#FFCA3A")
    ("WAITING" . "#D00000") ("CANCELLED" . "#686789")
    ("DONE" . "#89FC00")))
```

Is it okay to dump this code as-is into my theme file so that all faces are defined in the same place? I tried it and it *seems* to work just fine, but is it considered bad form to do this or is it likely to cause issues further down the road?

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you putting both `setq`s in the theme file, or just the second one about the faces?

Comment: @NickD That's a good question! I'm putting both in the theme file, just because the faces definitions probably don't make sense without first defining the keywords. Is that a bad idea?

Comment: I would put the keywords in the init file, simply because they should make sense even without the faces. Even if I don't load the theme file everything should work: it just wouldn't look pretty. Of course, if you separate them you'd have related things in two places: pick your poison :-)